# php passing on output to a variable

Tags: php

This might be easy, but i could not get solution for it as is novice and learning on the php

I want to put the output into a variable called $list so that it becomes

```
<?php   $list .= '<h3> <?php echo $this->escape($item->n_make); ?>  <?php echo $item->n_model; ?> 
          </h3>
        <p> <?php echo $item->n_month; ?>   <?php echo $item->n_year; ?> </p>
        <p> <?php echo $item->n_short_description; ?> </p>
        <hr/>'
?>
```

But the syntax is incorrect as its like php within php
How to get value of $list capturing in details

and can then use in explode function

```
  <?php     
$listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
$numberOfListings = count($listings);
 ---- conditions
echo $listings;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just simple concatenation:

```
$list .= '<h3> ' . $this->escape($item->n_make) . $item->n_model . '</h3>
    <p> ' . $item->n_month . ' ' . $item->n_year . '</p>
    <p> ' . $item->n_short_description . ' </p>
    <hr/>';
```

Comment: Thanks just one more - is showing undefined variable $list. How Is it also to be declared

Comment: First do this $list = " "; as you you have used $list .=
You can concatenate variable only when a variable already exists. 
So for writing like $list .= you must have to define $list = ""